# How to sort list of objects like array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, timestamp

I have a list of JSON objects. In each object, there is a unix timestamp field which is what I want to sort with. So I wrote a sorting function

```
function sortUnixTimestamp(a, b){
  var a = parseInt(a.timestamp);
  var b = parseInt(b.timestamp);
  return ((a > b) ? -1 : ((a < b) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Since objects are not array, I tried `[].sort.call(object).sort(sortUnixTimestamp);` but from time to time I get **[].sort.call(...).sort is not a function**

I also tried to sort it like an array by doing `(object).sort(sortUnixTimestamp);`, again, from time to time I get **(...).sort is not a function**

Time to time because it works half the time. Why does it work some of the time but not always? And how do I get around this issue?

Added:
Each object looks like this

```
{
    "field1": "string",
    "field2": "string",
    "timestamp": 0
}
```

So the list looks like

```
[
    {
      "field1": "string",
      "field2": "string",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "field1": "string",
      "field2": "string",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: How your original data looks like?

Comment: @FelixMosheev see updated question for JSON object definition

Comment: What is `object` exactly? You say it's a list. If it's not an array, is it from a library?

Comment: objects are in list []

Comment: @4castle it's pulled from a database, it is a list of JSON objects

Comment: @4castle see updated question

Comment: Is `object` perhaps still a string? Try calling `JSON.parse(object).sort`

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like:

```js
var data = [{
  timestamp: 3
}, {
  timestamp: 2
}, {
  timestamp: 1
}];

var result = data.sort((item1, item2) => item1.timestamp - item2.timestamp);

console.log(result);
```

You can use native array`s sort function.

Comment: What I don't understand here is JSON objects should not be treated as Array right? Also why would my original sort function only work some of the time?

Answer (score 0):

if your objects are in an array, you can sort them by their timestamp value:

```
var arrayObj = [
  {timestamp: 12},
  {timestamp: 10},
  {timestamp: 2},
  {timestamp: 23}
];
```

By calling the array.prototype.sort() method to sort the array of objects by their timestamp property as per below:

```
arrayObj.sort(function (a,b) {
  return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
});
```

This should output:

```
[ { timestamp: 2 },
{ timestamp: 10 },
{ timestamp: 12 },
{ timestamp: 23 } ]
```